# How to make Google Analytics linked Adsense Revenue report same as Adsense reporting revenue

Tags: google-analytics, adsense

I am trying to align adsense Revenue Data to understand the value of marketing efforts.

1) I have linked my adsense and google analytics account
2) I have checked that all timezones are Pacific Time

Problem: As seen below the exported Google Analytics **LINKED** Adsense revenue data does not match the exported Adsense Reporting data.

What is causing the mismatch of data and how can I make sure the data in both reports align?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests a few different possibilities: There is no guarantee that both AdSense and Analytics has time to load on your pages. Your time zones may not be set the same way in the two services.

- [About AdSense in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012185?hl=en)
- [Why do my statistics differ between AdSense and Analytics?](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6090783?hl=en)

That being said, there are clearly some bugs in the AdSense–Analytics integration. E.g. I’ve noticed that my AdSense revenue is reported in Analytics with [a double-currency-conversion](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Double-currency-conversion-of-AdSense-Revenue-in-Analytics/td-p/1641998).